# Last occurance of time relative to now()

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

What's the most elegant way to ask Postgres for the last 4:05pm relative to `now()`?

I have been writing a fairly elaborate `CASE` with `date_trunc`'s and my guess is it can be accomplished in a much cleaner manner.

I speak with reference to no table. i.e. There is no `FROM` in this query. Just a simple `SELECT`.

The result of this is either a `TIMESTAMP` at 4:05pm today, or yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is similar to what @Daniel already posted, but this is a bit faster (twice as fast in my tests on pg 9.3):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN now()::time > time '16:05'
            THEN now()::date + time '16:05'
            ELSE (now()::date - 1) + time '16:05' END AS ts;
```

[`now()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is the Postgres implementation of the SQL standard [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) (which you can use as well). I use `now()`, because it is shortest and fastest. [`CURRENT_TIME`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) and [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) are implemented with `now()` as well.

Note that you get a `timestamp [without time zone]` that is interpreted according to your current time zone setting.

Answer (score 2):

Start with today at 16:05 and if we're already past 16:05, subtract one day:

```
select current_date + interval '16:05'
       - interval '1 day'*(case when current_time>'16:05' then 0 else 1 end)
```

If a daylight saving time switch occurs during the interval, it should be taken care of implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

One more option (and a variation):

```
SELECT ts
FROM (VALUES (now()::date + time '16:05'), 
             ((now()::date - 1) + time '16:05')
     ) AS t (ts)
WHERE ts < now()
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 1 ;

SELECT x.ts
FROM (VALUES (now()::date + time '16:05')) AS t (ts)
     , LATERAL
      ( SELECT ts UNION ALL 
        SELECT ts - interval '1 day') AS x 
WHERE x.ts < now()
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```